# Facebook like usage of #! in url for content loaded through ajax

Tags: ajax, url, .htaccess, redirect

I am using ajax to load content for my site.
When I dynamically load a page http//www.example.com/a/b/c
I change my current page's url to http//www.example.com/xyz/#!/a/b/c by setting it through javascript using window.location

Now what I want to do is that when somebody enters a url http//www.example.com/xyz/#!/a/b/c in the browser, he should be directed to http//www.example.com/a/b/c instead of http//www.example.com/xyz/

This is similar to what is used on facebook
http//www.facebook.com/?ref=logo#!/reqs.php#friend
automatically takes me to
http//www.facebook.com/reqs.php#friend
when loaded without ajax.

I tried using javascript to implement this

```
    requestedURL = ""+window.location+"";
    position = requestedURL.search("#!");
    domainame = "http://localhost"
    if(position != -1){
        newpage = requestedURL.substr(position+2);
        requestedURL = "";
        window.location = domainame+newpage;
    }
```

This did work me but now every time when I load a page even through ajax, this script gets executed.

Can someone help me out with this.
A solution through .htaccess would also do for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something I would try to emulate from the routing module of my application (on the server side) instead of via Ajax.

Comment: I am hosting this site on my institute's server so dont have much privilege there. I would be glad if you could suggest some method through javascript redirection or htaccess.